# Controller to manage athletes

Tags: php, beginner, controller, laravel

I would appreciate if you could give me some advice about the code below. I am a student learning PHP programming and programming fundamentals. I have learned a lot from Stack Overflow but there are lot of things I don't know. I would like a senior developer's opinion on improving my codes overall quality.

This is a part of my API code. I wrote this using Laravel framework. I want to know how to refactor my code using repositories and service layers.

```
use Athlete\Requests\PlayerRequest;
use Sorskod\Larasponse\Larasponse;
use Athlete\Transformers\PlayerTransformer;
use Athlete\Repositories\Player\PlayerRepository;

class PlayersController extends ApiController {

    /**
     * @var \Sorskod\Larasponse\Larasponse $fractal
     */
    private $fractal;

    /**
     * @var \Athlete\Repositories\Player\PlayerRepository $repository
     */
    private $repository;

    /**
     * @var \Athlete\Requests\PlayerRequest $playerRequest
     */
    private $playerRequest;

    /**
     * @param \Sorskod\Larasponse\Larasponse $fractal
     * @param PlayerRepository $repository
     * @param \Athlete\Requests\PlayerRequest $playerRequest
     */
    public function __construct(Larasponse $fractal,
                                PlayerRepository $repository,
                                PlayerRequest $playerRequest
    )
    {
        $this->fractal = $fractal;
        $this->fractal->parseIncludes($this->getIncludes());

        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->playerRequest = $playerRequest;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * GET /players
     *
     * @param $sportId
     * @param $teamId
     * @return \Response
     */
    public function index($sportId, $teamId)
    {
        $limit = Request::get('limit') ?: 20;

        $offset = Request::get('offset') ?: 0;

        $team = Auth::user()->sports()->findOrfail($sportId)->teams()->findOrFail($teamId);

        $players = $this->repository->filterByTeam($team->id)->paginate($limit, $offset);

        $data = $this->fractal->collection($players, new playerTransformer(), 'players');

        return $this->respondWithSuccess($data);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     * POST /sports
     *
     * @param $sportId
     * @param $teamId
     * @return \Response
     */
    public function store($sportId, $teamId)
    {
        $formData = Input::all();

        $this->playerRequest->validate($formData);

        $team = Auth::user()->sports()->findOrFail($sportId)->teams()->findOrFail($teamId);

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            if(Input::hasFile('image')) {
                $formData = array_merge($formData, ['image' => Str::random()]);
            }

            $player = $team->players()->create($formData);

            //save weight, height of the player if they exists
            if(array_key_exists('weight_unit', $formData)) {

                $player->weight()->save(new Weight([
                    'unit' => $formData['weight_unit'],
                    'value' => $formData['weight_value']
                ]));
            }

            if(array_key_exists('height_unit', $formData)) {

                $player->height()->save(new Height([
                    'unit' => $formData['height_unit'],
                    'value' => $formData['height_value']
                ]));
            }

            $this->moveImage($player->id, $player->image);

            DB::commit();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();

            return $this->respondUnprocess($e->getMessage());
        }

        $data = $this->fractal->item($player, new PlayerTransformer());

        return $this->respondWithSuccess(array_merge($data, ['players_count' => Player::count()]));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     * GET /sports/{id}
     *
     * @param $sportId
     * @param $teamId
     * @param $playerId
     * @return \Response
     */
    public function show($sportId, $teamId, $playerId)
    {
        $team = Auth::user()->sports()->findOrFail($sportId)->teams()->findOrFail($teamId);

        $player = $team->players()->findOrFail($playerId);

        $data = $this->fractal->item($player, new playerTransformer());

        return $this->respondWithSuccess($data);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     * PUT /players/{playerId}
     *
     * @param $sportId
     * @param $teamId
     * @param $playerId
     * @return \Response
     * @throws \Laracasts\Validation\FormValidationException
     */
    public function update($sportId, $teamId, $playerId)
    {
        $formData = Input::all();

        $this->playerRequest->updateRules()->validate($formData);

        $team = Auth::user()->sports()->findOrFail($sportId)->teams()->findOrFail($teamId);

        $player = $team->players()->findOrFail($playerId);

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            // rename the image name to clear caching for mobile devices
            if(Input::hasFile('image')) {
                $path = storage_path("players/{$player->id}/{$player->image}");
                File::delete($path);

                $formData = array_merge($formData, ['image' => Str::random()]);
            }

            $player->update($formData);

            //update weight, height of the player
            if(array_key_exists('weight_unit', $formData)) {

                Weight::updateOrCreate([
                    'id' => $playerId
                ], [
                    'unit' => $formData['weight_unit'],
                    'value' => $formData['weight_value']
                ]);
            }

            if(array_key_exists('height_unit', $formData)) {

                Height::updateOrCreate([
                    'id' => $playerId
                ], [
                    'unit' => $formData['height_unit'],
                    'value' => $formData['height_value']
                ]);
            }

            $this->moveImage($player->id, $player->image);

            DB::commit();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();

            return $this->respondUnprocess('Unable to update the player!');
        }

        $data = $this->fractal->item($player, new PlayerTransformer());

        return $this->respondWithSuccess($data);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     * DELETE /players/{playerId}
     *
     * @param $sportId
     * @param $teamId
     * @param $playerId
     * @return \Response
     */
    public function destroy($sportId, $teamId, $playerId)
    {
        $team = Auth::user()->sports()->findOrFail($sportId)->teams()->findOrFail($teamId);

        $player = $team->players()->findOrFail($playerId);

        try {
            if($player->image != 'default.png') {
                $path = storage_path("players/{$player->id}");

                $player->delete();
                File::delete($path);
            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {

            return $this->respondUnprocess('Unable to delete the player!');
        }

        return $this->respondWithSuccess('Player has been successfully deleted.');
    }

    /**
     * Move image to app/storage path
     *
     * @param $path
     * @param $name
     */
    private function moveImage($path, $name)
    {
        if(Input::hasFile('image') && Input::file('image')->isValid()) {

            Input::file('image')->move(storage_path("players/$path"), $name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does)

Comment: So, is this part of a game? A sports simulation of some kind? Please add more info about what this code does.

Comment: This a part of Athlete Management Software. It can manage players, teams, sports, videos and skills. This is the PlayersController.

Comment: Also could you provide the code from the `ApiController`. I can see calls to methods such as `getIncludes()`, which I assume are declared inside the parent class.

Comment: I'm guessing by "managing players, teams, sports and skills" you mean that it collects data to define such items and allows those items to be edited in the event of changes.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

You are putting *way* too much logic into your controller methods. Most of the logic should be placed in a service that should be injected into the controller.

The logic in the controller methods really shouldn't do much more than grab a value from here, set a value there and maybe call a function on a service.

The most extreme way of achieving this would be to make the entire controller a service, creating a new controller and see how much you need to move back from the service into the controller.

In regards to the "how", you may want to take a look at Chris Fidao's talk about [hexagonal-architecture](http://fideloper.com/hexagonal-architecture),